# Retrieving object from firebase which contains the exact items in its attributes in an efficient way

Tags: json, firebase, performance, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

I am using Firebase and Xamarin Forms to deploy an app. I am trying to figure it out how to get an object (or several) matching one criteria. Let's say I have a collection of characters and each of them has different attributes like name, age, city and the last attribute is an array of string saying what kind of tools they have.

For example, having this three characters in the collection:

```
{                'characters':
                {
                    'char001': {
                        'name': 'John',
                        "tools":[ "knife", "MagicX", "laser", "fire" ]
                    },
                    'char002': {
                        'name': 'Albert',
                        "tools":[ "MagicX" ]
                    },
                    'char003': {
                        'name': 'Chris',
                        "tools":[ "pistol", "knife", "magicX" ]
                    }
                }
}
```

I want to retrieve the character(s) who has a ***knife*** and ***magicX***, so the query will give me as a result: char001, and char003.

That said, I have a large set of data, like +10.000 characters in the collection plus each character can have up to 10 items in ***tools***.

I can retrieve the objects if the attribute ***tools*** where just one string, but having ***tools*** as an array I have to iterate throw all the items of each character and see how many of them has a ***knife*** and then the same procedure looking for the one with ***magicX***, and the do the union of the two queries which is going to give me the result. This, in terms of speed, it's so slow.

I would like to do it on the back-end side directly, and just receive the correct data.

- **How could I perform the query in firebase?**

Thank you so much in advance,
Cheers.

Comment: Your second question here is off topic for Stack Overflow.  I suggest editing your question to focus on a single clear question, else it might get closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firebase, this is easy, **assuming that characters is a collection**...

If it's the case, one way to do it is to structure your "charachter" documents like so:

```
'char001': {
   name: "John",
   tools: { 
      knife: true,
      MagicX: true,
      laser: true
   }
}
```

This way, you'll be able to perform compound EQUALITY queries and get back all the characters with the tools you're searching for. Something like:

```
db.collection('characters').where('tools.knife', '==', true).where('tools.magicX', '==', true)
```

Mind you, you can combine up to 10 equality clauses in a query.

I hope this helps, search for "firestore compound queries" for more info.

Comment: Thanks for you input. I will try it!